# Best way to present multiple confirmation messages to user

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I've been asked to convert a `VB6` application to a `WebForms` environment `(C# .NET v4.5)`. The existing application presents multiple confirmation messages when the Save button is clicked.

```
EG. "You have entered X, which is less than Y. Are you sure?"
```

They want to preserve this functionality but I'm uncomfortable with this approach of spamming the user with (potentially) 10+ questions that they have to click through in order to save.  Not to mention that modern browsers allow users to disable multiple popups.

So does anyone have a more 'best practice' approach to this scenario?

Comment: Ok, after discussing with the team we've decided to go with a modal dialog displaying a dynamic list of warning messages with accompanying checkboxes. Users must confirm that they are ok with each warning before the 'Submit' button will continue the process.

Comment: You can answer your own question, once you have done with your solution. It may help future users with similar requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this requirement, here is the solution I came up with. It's a bit rough and I need to do further work on cleaning it up, but it might provide a starting point for someone in the future.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sam_Banks/df3cewg7/

It is a simple `<UL>` that is built up using `JQuery` as a result of validation checks run when a button is clicked.

```
<div>
    <label for="txtCaseOne">First Input</label>
    <input id="txtCaseOne" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="txtCaseTwo">Second Input</label>
    <input id="txtCaseTwo" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="OK" />
</div>
<div class="confirmationContainer">
    <div class="confirmationWindow">
        <ul class="warnings"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each list item consists of a message and a checkbox. The message text is clickable and takes the user to the target control so that they can check/edit a value as required.

The checkbox allows the user to register that they have confirmed the warning.

The user's confirmations are remembered so that they don't have to re-confirm if the dialog is closed & re-opened.

The page will not submit to the server unless all checkboxes have been clicked.

```
function submitFinalApproval() {
    var unconfirmed = $('.confirmationWindow').find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)');

    if (unconfirmed.length > 0) {
        alert("You cannot submit for Final Approval until all warnings are confirmed.");
        return false;
    }

    alert("Submitting");
    $('.confirmationWindow').dialog('close');
}

function cancelFinalApproval() {
    $('.confirmationWindow').dialog('close');
}

function saveCheckedWarnings() {
    $('.confirmationContainer').removeData();

    var checkedWarnings = $('.confirmationWindow input:checked');

    checkedWarnings.each(function () {
        var warning = $(this).parent().siblings('span').text();
        $('.confirmationContainer').data(warning, "true");
    });
}

function selectWarning(target) {
    $('.confirmationWindow').dialog('close');
    target.focus().select();
}

function appendWarning(message, target) {
    var label = $('<span>');
    label.text(message);
    label.on('click', function () {
        selectWarning(target);
    });

    var checkboxLabel = $('<label>');
    if ($('.confirmationContainer').data(message)) {
        checkboxLabel.append($('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />'));
    } else {
        checkboxLabel.append($('<input type="checkbox" />'));
    }
    checkboxLabel.append('OK');

    $('.warnings')
        .append($('<li>')
        .append(label)
        .append(checkboxLabel));
}

$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {

    //if page passes error validation

    $('.warnings').empty();

    // If warning condition 1 fails
    appendWarning("Please note that Condition 1 is odd. Would you like to continue?", $('#txtCaseOne'));
    // If warning condition 2 fails
    appendWarning("Condition 2 set to Fizz while Buzz. Are you sure?", $('#txtCaseTwo'));
    // If warning condition 3 fails
    appendWarning("Condition 3. Are you sure?", $('#txtCaseTwo'));

    $('.confirmationWindow').dialog('open');

    return false;
});

$('.confirmationWindow').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: 'noDialogTitle',
    buttons: {
        "Submit for Final Approval": submitFinalApproval,
        Cancel: cancelFinalApproval
    },
    close: function () {
        saveCheckedWarnings();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.Net `<asp:ValidationSummery>` control for your purpose.
Please find below code for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table bgcolor="#b0c4de" cellspacing="10">
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Name:</td>
     <td><asp:TextBox id="txt_name" runat="server"/></td>
     <td>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
     ControlToValidate="txt_name" 
     ErrorMessage="Please Enter Name"
     Text="*" 
     runat="server"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Travel Type:</td>
     <td>
     <asp:RadioButtonList id="rlist_type" 
     RepeatLayout="Flow"
     runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem>Bus</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Train</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Flight</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </td>
     <td>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
     ControlToValidate="rlist_type"
     ErrorMessage="Please Select Travel Type"
     InitialValue=""
     Text="*"
     runat="server"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server"/></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<asp:ValidationSummary
ShowMessageBox="true"
ShowSummary="false"
HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
EnableClientScript="true"
runat="server"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but we are already using validation controls for mandatory fields, etc. We need something that asks the user to confirm or cancel the action. If they confirm it then the Save action continues.